# How to save font size in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
/* The code that actually changes the font size */

function fontSize(selectTag) {
    var listValue = selectTag.options[selectTag.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("text").style.fontSize = listValue;
}

/*my failed text to try and save the font size*/

function onClick(){
        var button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.addEventListener("click", save, false);
        display();
    }
        function saveFont(){
            localStorage.setItem();
        }
        
        window.addEventListener("load", onClick, false);
```

```html
  
  <!-- This is how they choose their font size -->
  <select onchange="fontSize(this);" size="11">
  <option>xx-small</option>
  <option>x-small</option>
  <option>small</option>
  <option>medium</option>
  <option>large</option>
  <option>x-large</option>
  <option>xx-large</option>
  <option>100%</option>
  <option>250%</option>
  <option>2cm</option>
  <option>100px</option>
</select>
        <br>
        <!-- this is how i would save it since they don't physically click a button -->
        <input type="button" id="save" value="Save Font Size">
        
        
        <!-- The body tag is has an 'id="text' "-->
```

So changing the font size isn't an issue, i've got that down. But for the life of me i can't save it to HTML local storage, so that when i change page or refresh the font size remains the same as what i changed it to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's important that when you attempt to get a CSS property value that you get the final computed value of the element's property. Some properties are not set on the `style` property of the element, but instead are set via CSS classes or other selectors. Attempting to get such properties with `element.style` will yeild an empty string in those cases. To make sure you get the final value, use **[`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)**.

Next, to get and set items to localStorage, you use the **[`localStorage.setItem(key, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)** and **[`localStorage.getItem(key)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)** API's. Your code is:

```
localStorage.setItem();
```

which doesn't pass the key name or a value, so nothing gets set. Here's how setting and gettting `localStorage` values should be written:

**Setting font-size to localStorage:**

```
localStorage.setItem("font", window.getComputedStyle(DOMelementInQuestion).fontSize);
```

**Get the font-size back out:**

```
var storedFont = localStorage.getItem("font");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/qPBXNX)**

Note: the snippet below can't be run because code snippets on StackOverflow are sandboxed and can't access localStorage. The **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/qPBXNX)** is a working example using the code in the below snippet.

```js
function setFontSize() {
  var select = document.getElementById("text");
  var listValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  select.style.fontSize = listValue;
  localStorage.setItem("font-size", listValue);
}

function getFontSize() {
  var select = document.getElementById("text");
  select.value = localStorage.getItem("font-size");
  select.style.fontSize = select.value;
}

window.onload = getFontSize();
```

```html
<select onchange="setFontSize();" size="11" id='text'>
  <option>xx-small</option>
  <option>x-small</option>
  <option>small</option>
  <option>medium</option>
  <option>large</option>
  <option>x-large</option>
  <option>xx-large</option>
  <option>100%</option>
  <option>250%</option>
  <option>2cm</option>
  <option>100px</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott is bang on his explanation. I personally didn't know about `window.getComputedStyle` so that one is new for me.

I re-wrote your script to achieve what you need. Its not bullet proof but it showcases how it can be done.

http://jsbin.com/cesususose/edit?html,js,output